# Jenkins can not connect to git repository over ssh

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm very new with Jenkins, and I'm trying to learn how to use it. I have setup the Jenkins on my small Windows-based server, and I have another server (raspberry) where I have initialized a small git project. When I try to add this git repository to the Jenkins, it can not connect to it no matter what. Here's what I have tried so far.

I can check, that the connection is working to the git server by using `git ls-remote -h ssh://gitserver@192.168.50.152:22/home/gitserver/GitProject/.git` command from any computer within the network, and I get a response after giving my password. I have saved this password as a "Username with password" -kind to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Credentials. Then, I have selected this from the Credentials drop down, but all I get is this error: "Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command: git.exe ls-remote -h ssh://gitserver@192.168.50.152:22/home/gitserver/GitProject/.git HEAD"

Interesting part is, that if I try that command given with the "HEAD" at the end, I get just empty line, but no errors. Could this be an indicator to some kind of an issue? Here's a picture of the configuration. Am I doing something wrong? I have SSH authentication right now via password and ssh-public key. I have tried the SSH-public key as a credential, but no luck.

[image: Jenkins Source Code Management Error]

I'm very new to Jenkins, and just starting to learn, but I could not find an answer to this. Many articles were just pointing out how to connect to GitHub project, but I want to connect to this local project sitting on a raspberry pi, as an exercise.

Comment: check that you're able to reach port 22 on 192.168.50.152 from the server running jenkins

Comment: @erik258 yes, this connection is working, and I'm able to connect to that server from the Jenkins machine in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue was with Jenkins and specifically with the SSH plugin it is using to connect. After updating everything, and Jenkins restarted, the connection is now working, and I can confirm this by clicking the "Build Now", and checking the Build log, Jenkins did fetch the info from the Raspberry server, and it is now sitting at the data-folder of this server!

So, for the rest of the people having this issue, try to update all plugins and then restart the Jenkins.